# Rearrange filters option missing?

Tags: 7, views

How can I rearrange the weight of the exposed filters?
In Drupal 6 I had that option, and in Drupal 7 it has disappeared.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select 'And/Or' next to Filter Criteria, this will show a popup where you can rearrange them.